# Why is Maven fetching the wrong Jetty version?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am using spring boot and have below dependencies. If you look at the `jetty` dependencies, I expect it to fetch all the jetty dependencies with "9.4.1.v20170120" suffix but it's fetching the wrong version. I am using the same thing in another project where it fetches it correctly. Please take a look at images.

pom.xml entries:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: maybe you have defined this version in your parent pom

Comment: do you specify anywhere the dependecies with versions?

Comment: I have tried with the same dependencies you have and it is not happening to me. Can you try to delete all maven repo and redownload dependencies

Answer (score 3):

It is maven transitive dependency resolution.

> By default Maven resolves version conflicts with a nearest-wins
>   strategy

When resolving dependencies and there is a conflict between libraries Maven selects the library that is nearer to the root. In your case it is `javax.servlet-api.3.1.0.jar`

See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html

Comment: I don't think that this is what's happening. `spring-boot-starter-parent` includes dependency management for all of the Jetty modules shown in the screenshot so they should all have the version 9.4.1.v20170120 yet there's also some 9.3.11 modules in there. That tells me that something (the parent or another imported bom) is managing some of the versions

Comment: Mike..your answer gave me the direction. Actually it was eclipse jetty server dependency from parent pom which was causing this issue. I resolved it by manually putting the jetty version i required under dependencymanagement tag. Thanks for taking pain...1 up for that